# How to install NLB on 2 win 7 machines with IIS 7.5

Tags: windows-7, windows-nlb

Is it possible to make a load balancing cluster that uses 2 win7 machines with IIS installed.

I want to make a cluster between 2 such machines.

I figured out how to add the Network Load Balancing Manager feature to WIN7 and I am using this [tutorial](http://comtechsolution.blogspot.ro/2011/11/steps-to-configure-network-load.html).

Can this be done, because so far by trying to connect to those machines? I haven't managed to make them work as a Win2008Server R2.

The error I receive is :

> Could not locate NLB on specified computer.

Comment: Windows 7 does not support Network Load Balancing. I'd suggest you'd use a Server OS such as Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am really asking, whether this is possible using Win7

Comment: @Floradu88 I have no idea what `2in7` means, but you're using the wrong operating system for this job. End of discussion, really.

Comment: @Dan It means win7 won't work, this is the answer I was trying to get. Add this as an answer.

Comment: @Floradu88 Fair comment, sorry. We have lots of people come by who won't accept the answer :)

Comment: I am willing to accept an answer that helps me accomplish balancing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows 7 does not support network load balancing. You will need to install a Server OS such as Windows Server 2008, trial versions of which can be found on the Microsoft website.